# Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error where **e** is a MouseEvent.

My HTML that involves the problematic checkbox click event is like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid  #adadad;border-bottom:1px solid  #adadad;">
        <td>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hfOptionProductID" value='<%#Eval("Key.ProductID")%>' />
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hfOptionModelNumber" value='<%#Eval("Key.BTModel")%>' />
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfAssetId" value='<%#Eval("Value.AssetID")%>' />
            <p>
               <%#Eval("Key.Name")%><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chbxOption" class="chkOlcs" onclick="chkOlcs_onClick(e);"/>
            </p>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlOlcs" class="pnlOlcs" Visible="False">
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkDomain" class="chkDomain" onclick="chkDomain_onClick(e)" Text="I want to link my license to a specific domain and its subdomains." /><br/>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDomain" class="txtDomain"  style="padding: 3px 5px; text-align: center; width: 200px;" placeholder="Enter a domain name"  ValidationGroup="OptionValidationGroup" disabled />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDomainError" class="lblDomain" Visible="False" style="color: red;"/><br/>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAny" class="chkAny" onclick="chkAny_onClick(e)" Text="I do not want to link my license to a specific domain."/><br/>
            </asp:Panel>
            <br />
       </td>               
   </tr>     
</ItemTemplate>
```

In the above HTML, this is the problematic part:

**<%#Eval("Key.Name")%><asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chbxOption" class="chkOlcs" onclick="chkOlcs_onClick(e);"/>**

For some unknown reason, when I run this in debug from Visual Studio in my Edge browser, I get the error.

Somehow **e** gets undefined and never reaches the Javascript function calls.

Here's the Javascript function definition:

```
function chkOlcs_onClick(e) {
    var chkOlcs = $('#' + e.target.id);
    var pnlOlcs = chkOlcs.parent().parent().parent().find('.pnlOlcs');

    var isChecked = e.target.checked;
    if (isChecked) {
        pnlOlcs.show();
    } else {
        pnlOlcs.hide();
    }
}
```

Now to make this worse: When run from the deployed web page, the error doesn't occur.

I have read pretty much all the similar issues with this error, but none seem to apply. I am open to any help.

Answer (score 1):

(Unless ASP.NET does something weird (I don't use ASP.NET, you didn't tag the question as being about [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)) with `onclick` attributes) `e` isn't a mouse event. It is undefined. The error message tells you that.

[`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) is a mouse event, but that's deprecated.

It is recommended to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of intrinsic event attributes (like `onclick`).

`element.addEventListener('click', chkOlcs_onClick)` would pass a mouse event as the first argument.